# Calling UITapGestureRecognizer on specific views in a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have four views in my view controller.
I want to call specific function on touching specific View
For example If I touch on View 1 in iPhone screen, I want to call corresponding function.

I have the View Controller and the 4 views in the storyboard. How can I load those specific views in my code and then on View touch implement some function.

Answer (score 0):

Individual touch gesture for all 4 views with corresponding selector methods will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** If you are having separate sub classes for each UIViews then you can simply implement the UIView methods

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

to detect touches.